# Make subprocess find git executable on Windows

Tags: python, windows, git, path, subprocess

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('git status')
print 'result: ', proc.communicate()
```

I have git in my system path, but when I run subprocess like this I get:
`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

How can I get subprocess to find git in the system path?

Python 2.6 on Windows XP.

Comment: The real problem isn't that subprocess isn't using `PATH`, but that git is installed as 'git.cmd', rather than 'git.exe', which would be found by subprocess.Popen.

Comment: This occurred for me using `subprocess.check_output(...)` on windows 10 after updating git to 2.19.1. Worked before the update. Now does not even work with `shell=True`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you see here is that the Windows API function [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), used by subprocess under the hood, doesn't auto-resolve other executable extensions than `.exe`. On Windows, the 'git' command is really installed as `git.cmd`. Therefore, you should modify your example to explicitly invoke `git.cmd`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('git.cmd status')
print 'result: ', proc.communicate()
```

The reason `git` works when `shell==True` is that the Windows shell auto-resolves `git` to `git.cmd`.

### Eventually, resolve git.cmd yourself:

```
import subprocess
import os.path

def resolve_path(executable):
    if os.path.sep in executable:
        raise ValueError("Invalid filename: %s" % executable)

    path = os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep)
    # PATHEXT tells us which extensions an executable may have
    path_exts = os.environ.get("PATHEXT", ".exe;.bat;.cmd").split(";")
    has_ext = os.path.splitext(executable)[1] in path_exts
    if not has_ext:
        exts = path_exts
    else:
        # Don't try to append any extensions
        exts = [""]

    for d in path:
        try:
            for ext in exts:
                exepath = os.path.join(d, executable + ext)
                if os.access(exepath, os.X_OK):
                    return exepath
        except OSError:
            pass

    return None

git = resolve_path("git")
proc = subprocess.Popen('{0} status'.format(git))
print 'result: ', proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Oh, ok.  I'm not using Windows anymore, so I can't confirm this answer, but I'm just going to assume you're right.  Thanks.

Comment: Also check [this python bug report][1].

  [1]: http://bugs.python.org/issue17023

"If you add a directory into PATH on Windows so that the directory is in quotes, subprocess does not find executables in it."

Comment: The environment variable that lists executable extensions is called PATHEXT, not PATHEXTS. (The code as given will always fall back to ".exe;.bat;.cmd", since PATHEXTS typically won't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "status"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The first argument of `subprocess.Popen` takes a `shlex.split`-like list of arguments.

or:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("git status", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This is not recommended, as you are launching a shell then launching a process in the shell.

Also, you should use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to retrieve the result.

Comment: No, Popen takes either a string or a list. See  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Depends -- if you have arguments, then you must use a list. Otherwise, you're just invoking `"git status"` and not `git status`.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend, see http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system . Please read the docs before spreading misinformation. The subprocess module can be confusing enough as it is.

Comment: `shell=True` is required if you do not use a list of arguments.

Comment: That's because you're on a Unix system, with `shell=False`, a default argument. On Unix with `shell=True`, it would run "correctly". It converts lists to a string internally anyhow on Windows. Again, please read the documentation.

Comment: What error do you receive? The docs are fairly explicit about the only time you need to pass `shell=True` on Windows being if you're running a shell builtin. If you're seeing incorrect behavior, a bug report is probably in order.

Comment: Your first snippet yields the same error, but the second one works.

Comment: Oh lordy, you do indeed need `shell=True` if you're on Windows, maybe.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue8557 . The discussion in the comments is enlightening,

Comment: The reason that shell invocation works is simply that the shell auto-resolves 'git' against 'git.cmd', not just 'git.exe' like the Windows API does.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in 2020, with With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), Python 2.6 or older is no longer supported.

See [commit 45a87a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45a87a83bb5eb146816bc98026fafaa9d912fc92) (07 Jun 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6361eb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6361eb73c6dc147e94b02673f387c0345d8d15d2), 18 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`CodingGuidelines`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45a87a83bb5eb146816bc98026fafaa9d912fc92): specify Python 2.7 is the oldest version
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> In [0b4396f068](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b4396f0688f6c82ada83eab68b1c8dd3669d8bf) ("`git-p4`: make python2.7 the oldest supported version", 2019-12-13, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a0fa1709c188d8be05aa573fa914d115f55aab1) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7d14a44285d3ec4b25bf9e3b7df701221350661)), git-p4 was updated to only support 2.7 and newer. Since Python 2.6 is pretty much ancient history, update CodingGuidelines to show that 2.7 is the oldest version supported.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need to pass `env` in to Popen, something like:

```
import subprocess, os
proc = subprocess.Popen('git status', env=os.environ, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The default `env` is equivalent to os.environ.