# How to install subprocess module for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

pip is not able to find this module, as well as me on pypi website.
Could you please tell me the secret, how to install it?

I need the module to spawn new shell process via subprocess.call. I have seen a lot of examples, where people use `import subprocess`, but no one shows how it was installed.

Error, that i got (just in case i've lost my mind and does not understand what is going on):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\tests-runner>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 27, in main
    subprocess.call('py.test')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: it's builtin, you don't have to install it. what is your python version?

Comment: The `subprocess` module is part of the standard library, it doesn't need (can't, actually) be installed. The error you get indicates that the *executable* that is supposed to be run as a subprocess can't be found, not the `subprocess` module itself. Might be an issue with the working directory, `$PATH`, or the executable not being an `.exe`.

Comment: What type of file is `py.test`? Windows doesn't know how it should execute a file with a `.test` extension, so you'd need to at least specify an interpreter to execute it with. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965175/make-subprocess-find-git-executable-on-windows/10555130) for an example of this problem with `git.cmd`.

Comment: try `py.test.exe` name. Windows might fail to add `.exe` suffix because it thinks that the file already has it (`.test`). Here's [how Windows search for the executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279)

Comment: One update: I see this error only if I execute in IDEL (Python GUI) or even directly in Windows dos shell. If I execute it in GIT shell as commandline it works fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no need to install this module in Python 2.7. It is a standard module that is built in.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) shows that it was added to the library for Python version 2.4. It's been with us for a long time now.

---

The error that you show in your question update is nothing more prosaic than a file not found error. Likely the executable file that you are attempting to call `Popen` on cannot be found.

That traceback indicates that `subprocess` is installed and has been imported. The problem is simply that the call to `subprocess.call('py.test')` is failing.

---

For future reference, this is the type of traceback you encounter when attempting to import a module that has not been installed:

```
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Answer (score 2):

The error-text is misleading. Most subprocess-commands expect the shellcmd to be submitted as a list of strings.

In these cases i strongly recommend  the usage of the shlex module:

```py
    import shlex
    
    shell_cmd = "test.py"
    
    subprocess_cmd = shlex.split(shell_cmd)
    subprocess.call(subprocess_cmd)
```

or in this simple case just:

```
    subprocess.call(["test.py"])
```